# Normalisation from 1nf to 2nf

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I have converted the following 1NF table to 2NF as follows. Still having doubt if I have done it right and also unable to determine the transitive dependency.

I believe - cdName is transitively dependent on cdId via date.

Thanks for any advice.

[image: 1NF]

[image: 2NF]

Comment: This question might be more at home on DBA.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - `cdName` should be in the table keyed by 'cdId'.  You should also have a table keyed by `recId` with the `recName` attribute.

(Your "band" table has duplicate entires, but that's a data issue, not a design issue.)

Comment: Hi, to clarify you mean the 2nf is correct? You mentioned I should have a table keyed by recId with recName which I have (cdId, recId, recName) I added CdId as a foreign key

Comment: No, your result is not 2NF - your guess was correct that `cdName` depends on `cdId`.  To me your keys should be:  `bandId`, `recId`, and `cdId` (FKs to `recId` and `bandId`)

Comment: So, cdName is transitively dependant on cdID via date. With regards to the tables, I have separated them into 3 tables as you mentioned - bandId, recId, CdId. Is my foreign key wrong or tables are wrong? Tnks.